# String isn't splitting, but file is being read

Tags: c#, parsing, text, file-io, split

```
public void LoadWorldMap()
{
    string path = "..\\Bin\\Assets\\WorldMap\\WorldMap.txt";
    //Open the file and read it. 
    string[] fileText = File.ReadAllLines(path);

    for (int index = 0; index < 320; index++)
    {
       string line = fileText[index];
       string[] tokens = line.Split(' ');

       System.Console.WriteLine(tokens[0]);
    }
}
```

The file looks like this:

```
0   0   0   0   0

0   1   0   0   0

0   2   0   0   0

0   3   0   0   0

0   4   0   0   0

0   5   0   0   0
```

No commas, which is why it is

```
line.Split(' ');
```

However, when I output tokens[0] it is the entire line, not split.
tokens[1] to tokens[4] is empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure those things that aren't commas are spaces and not something else?

Comment: I don't understand. You don't see `0 1 0 0 0` and `0 4 0 0 0` when you debug your code?

Comment: I am trying to split the single line, for every line. So tokens[0] should just output 0's and nothing else. As 0's are the first string in every line.

Comment: They might not be spaces, they might be tabbed spacing. How do I do that? I copy from excel to a notepad, and it creates "tabs" of spacing I guess.

Comment: Thank you David Schwartz. I am not sure what it is, but I copy/pasted it from the txt file into the compiler, and it works now. Make this your answer, so I can choose it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others noted the chars between the numbers are not spaces, but space like chars. The following regex will split the number tokens correctly regardless of what space type char is in the line.

```
string[] tokens = Regex.Split(line, @"\s+");
```

Answer (score 1):

As user2948630 mentioned the space character could be a tabbed space. It could also be a non breaking space if you copied text from a web page, or some other non printable character. To make sure the split character works for all possible spaces you could use a regular expression. For example,

```
string[] tokens = Regex.Split(line, @"\s+");
```

The \s metacharacter is used to find a whitespace character.

A whitespace character can be a:

- space character
- tab character
- carriage return character
- new line character
- vertical tab character
- form feed character

The + will find one or more occurrences of a whitespace character.